# What is the right logging approach when using Spring Batch?

Tags: java, logging, spring-batch

What is the right logging approach when using Spring Batch? Should I use log4j (or something similar) or Spring Batch provides some instruments that help me to instantiate a logger and use it? Maybe some sort of dependency injection of the logger?

Answer (score 3):

I'd used log4j. and its the simple and nice approach.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure the original poster's question was answered, so I'll try restating this a bit.  In Spring Batch you may have multiple threads going, and you may want to have job-specific logging, so that all events for a particular job are logged into a single log file. You want a Logger whose scope is tied directly to the job you are processing.  When the job finishes, the logger (and all references to the logger) go away.

So when you submit **Job#1**, all events are logged to **"job_1.log"**; when you submit **Job#2**, its events are logged to **"job_2.log"**, etc.

In log4j, when you do **"Logger.getLogger('mylogger')"** you are telling the LogManager to get **'mylogger'** out of the cache and give it to you.  What you really want is a new instance of the logger, configured using the configuration of mylogger. In Spring this might be typically done with a prototype bean.  Every time you ask the context for **'mylogger'** you would get a new instance.

Comment: Note that log4j also has a feature called Nested Diagnostic Contexts to accomplish the same thing on a per-thread basis: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#Nested_Diagnostic_Contexts

Answer (score 2):

You should think about Slf4J (logging API) + Logback (logging implementation) as Log4j is intented to be succeeded by this duet.

More: 
http://www.slf4j.org/ 
http://logback.qos.ch/